# How to use paging in a table in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I am trying to use paging system in a table as mentioned in this [post](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/823490/Bootstrap-Table-With-Sorting-Searching-and-Paging) but it doesn't seem to work

What is expected:

[image]

What I am getting:

[image]

I have placed all the styles in the head section and all the scripts at the bottom of the body section as usual, But I am not getting why it is not working any guess

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="display table" width="100%">
        <thead>  
          <tr>  
            <th>ENO</th>  
            <th>EMPName</th>  
            <th>Country</th>  
            <th>Salary</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>  
        <tbody>  
          <tr>  
            <td>001</td>  
            <td>Anusha</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>10000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>002</td>  
            <td>Charles</td>  
            <td>United Kingdom</td>  
            <td>28000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>003</td>  
            <td>Sravani</td>  
            <td>Australia</td>  
            <td>7000</td>  
          </tr>  
           <tr>  
            <td>004</td>  
            <td>Amar</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>18000</td>  
          </tr>  
          <tr>  
            <td>005</td>  
            <td>Lakshmi</td>  
            <td>India</td>  
            <td>12000</td>  
          </tr>  
        </tbody>  
    </table>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').dataTable();
    });
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

*Note: I have deleted some rows from the table to ignore the stack overflow error*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script isn't loaded yet. And you are calling on the function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
</script>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Place the external script tags above the internal script.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

/*Now the external js are loaded and you can call any function from here.*/
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
</script>
```

**Edit 2 as requested**:

`dataTable()` is a method which lies inside the script:

The inline script gets executed as it is loaded. But the external script takes time to load and it is placed below your inline script.

Hence, you are calling the method before it is defined.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views, It worked but still I am not getting why it didn't worked.

Comment: one more thing above code works fine for `bootstrap 3.2` but if I try to change `stylesheet` and `script` for bootstrap 4.0 then it doesn't work, Is there any other way to do it in bootstrap 4.0.

Comment: Updated the answer. Always remember to download the way they support each other. `bootstrap`, `jquery`, `datatables` . check it https://datatables.net/download/

Answer (score 0):

Re-order your scripts to look like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').dataTable();
  });
</script>
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

Hope this helps!